# What difference between Session.get() and EntityManager.find() Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm

What difference between `Session.get()` and `EntityManager.find()`? When we should use one of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate provides [implementation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#architecture-overview) for JPA as well as its own API.

Actually, both methods do the same thing: [obtaining an entity by primary key](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-find).

The `EntityManager.find()` is JPA specified way. `Session.get()` is hibernate API way.